# Is it possible to highlight unclosed bracket in python jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I some times forgot to close bracket and it leads to invalid syntax further, that I try to fix, but the case is just in bracket. In R there is red light on the left side of the line to warn for such errors.

Comment: maybe you need some extension which uses `linter` for Python